# Can WebMethods Be Defined and Called In the 'Code Behind' of a Razor cshtml Page?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, webmethod

I'm currently migrating my site from .aspx to .cshtml.

With my old site, a few of my pages required interaction between javascript and the server through webmethods. This was easily achieved, you simply define a webmethod in the code behind of the .aspx page, then post to it at URL = [page path].aspx/[function name].

I've done quite a bit of looking around, but haven't been able to determine whether an equivalent process is possible with a .cshtml page.

So far I've worked around this by producing a folder with .aspx pages whose sole purpose is to provide these webmethods.

Obviously I'd like to get rid of these. Is this a feature with razor?

Comment: Absolutely not, web methods are not part of MVC. You would typically define an action on your controller and simply call that action using AJAX. The code that lived within your web method would now live within the controller action.

Comment: If your interaction is between your JavaScript and some methods on the server side, you should replace them with methods created in WebAPI.